# Como criar tabelas no postgreSQL utilizando geração automática de id de chave primaria?

Tags: postgresql

Quero que me perdoe-me por essa postagem, talvez seja a dúvida de alguém, mas vamos lá...

Eu sei que o programador tem que dominar algumas coisas, e essa coisas são consideradas como trívias, por exemplo; Todo programador tem que saber inglês avançado para não ficar dependendo de cursos e sim de documentação Oficial de uma determinada tecnologia, todo programador tem que saber Orientação Objeto e todo programador tem que saber o básico de SQL, então... Eu não sei de todas essas coisas mais estou aprendendo moderadamente os assuntos.

Eu tinha o costume de criar minhas aplicações no MySQL, mas estou com um cliente que quer fazer de qualquer jeito o sistema no PostgreSQL, com ele não tem conversa, mas hoje fiquei sem emprego e tem surgido esses trabalhos rápidos para fazer, então estou abraçando e preciso muito da ajuda de vocês.

Atualmente estou precisando implementar o sistema de segurança de uma aplicação, e necessário eu criar algumas tabelas com instrução SQL, o projeto que estou fazendo ele já faz muita coisa para mim, e cria algumas tabelas de forma automática, estou usando Spring Boot, porém a parte de segurança é necessário criar as tabelas através de instrução SQL, eu sei fazer sem nenhum problema em banco de dados MySQL, mas da mesma forma que sei fazer em Mysql não sei realizar a criação do banco de dados em PosgreSQL, estou me deparando com erros de sintaxe, e não tenho infelizmente um banco de dados de teste para criar o sistema, eu sei que isso é um enorme erro, mas vou tentar resolver esse problema mais pra frente.

Tentei pesquisar cursos Gratuitos de como criar as tabelas em SQL, mas existem poucas informações na internet em relação a isso, é claro que existem muita informação em inglês, mas não estou conseguindo entender porque ainda estou aprendendo inglês.

As tabelas são justamente essas abaixo, estou tentando criar essas tabelas no PostgreSQL, mas parece que para criar uma chave auto incremento tem que criar ela separadamente, eu fiz algumas tentativas, mas estou com medo que danificar as configurações do banco no servidor Heroku.

```
CREATE TABLE usuario (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    senha VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    ativo BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
    data_nascimento DATE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE grupo (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE permissao (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE usuario_grupo (
    codigo_usuario BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    codigo_grupo BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (codigo_usuario, codigo_grupo),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(codigo),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_grupo) REFERENCES grupo(codigo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE grupo_permissao (
    codigo_grupo BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    codigo_permissao BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (codigo_grupo, codigo_permissao),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_grupo) REFERENCES grupo(codigo),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_permissao) REFERENCES permissao(codigo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Será que alguém poderia generosamente me dizer como ficariam essas tabelas se fossem feitas em PosgreSQL ?

Ao tentar executar a Query  da criação de usuario_grupo deu o seguinte erro;

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:     codigo_usuario BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
                                 ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
SQL state: 42601
Character: 55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para definir um coluna como o `auto increment` do MySQL use o tipo chamado  `serial` ou `bigserial` isso vai criar uma sequence que vai atulizando o número a cada registro inserido.

A DDL da tabela deve ficar dessa forma. O PostgreSQL não trabalha com engines como o MySQL logo pode omitir definição dele.

```
CREATE TABLE usuario (
    codigo BIGSERIAL,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    senha VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    ativo BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
    data_nascimento DATE
    PRIMARY KEY(codigo)
);
```

[Documentação postgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Comment: será que poderia me dá mais uma ajuda? Como ficaria a tabela usuario_grupo ?

Comment: @wladyband deu algum erro? essa tabela não tem nenhum campo serial.

Comment: eu atualizei minha postagem, dá uma olhada por favor   :(

Comment: @wladyband em tipos inteiros você não especifica o tamanho, pode remover aquele `(20)` depois do `BIGINT`

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

No PostgreSQL o `AUTO_INCREMENT` é **sempre** feito por meio de `SEQUENCES`. Quando se usa o tipo numérico `BIGSERIAL`, um objeto de `SEQUENCE` é criado implicitamente pelo servidor.

> Os tipos de dado serial e bigserial não são tipos verdadeiros, mas
>   meramente uma notação conveniente para definir colunas identificadoras
>   únicas (semelhante à propriedade AUTO_INCREMENTO existente em alguns
>   outros bancos de dados).

Particularmente, eu não sou fã dessas "conveniências" e prefiro ter controle do que está acontecendo.

Sugiro a criação do objeto de `SEQUENCE` **manualmente** e recomendo evitar a utilização desses tipos numéricos tais como `SERIAL` e `BIGERIAL`:

```
--
-- PRIMEIRO, CRIA-SE A SEQUENCE MANUALMENTE
--
CREATE SEQUENCE public.sq_pk_usuario START 1;

-- 
-- CRIACAO DA TABELA COM VALOR DEFAULT 
--
CREATE TABLE public.usuario
(
    codigo BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.sq_pk_usuario'),
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    senha VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    ativo BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
    data_nascimento DATE,

    CONSTRAINT pk_usuario PRIMARY KEY (codigo)
);
```